# How to clean dumpstate/logcat with adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

Is there anyway to clean dumpstate/logcat data with an adb shell? *#9900# is not working on my phone.

I tried `adb logcat -c`, but it didn't help.

I m struggling with an "Insufficient memory space" problem and cannot install any new apps. I have 5gb of those files and cannot get rid of them :P

Comment: The logs presented by `adb logcat` live in circular buffers in RAM, and do not occupy any disk space. Where are you finding these files?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `adb logcat -c`

> -c : clear (flush) the entire log and exit

This a just clears the current buffer of the logcat, but the logs you are referring to aren't created by Logcat but rather by system itself. It should be located under /data/log and this have root permissions. You can delete it if your device is rooted.

If unrooted, you can try to go to settings>storage>cache to clear the cache and see if this helps. I don't know if this can help removing the files, this is a ROM bug, I don't know if there is any available solution without rooting.